# sharer or feed dialog url count

Tags: api, facebook-sharer

I need to share the URLs and get the share count for each of them. I've been googling a lot and trying this 2 ways:

1.- First I've been using the deprecated "facebook.com/sharer.php" to share an URL, then I run FQL query like this: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url="...here the URL..."

In this case, it never counts the first share. E.g. I share the URL for the first time and FQL query gives me zero. Then I share URL for the second time - then the FQL query gives me 1. etc.

2.- I've found a message here that sharer is deprecated from March 2011, and it's better to use "facebook.com/dialog/feed" for the purposes of URL sharing. But if I share URLs with the feed dialog, FQL query always gives me zero.

The question is: How do I share URLs and get the valid count for them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new **Send Button** which replaces the old sharer.php that is not going to be supported.

Send Button is easy integrated:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

(see the example in right)

To count the shares you can use **Insights table** 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#plugins

- domain_widget_send_views
- domain_widget_send_clicks
- domain_widget_send_inbox_views
- domain_widget_send_inbox_clicks

I also belive that this reflect the like count also.

Hope this helps!